# Enable Yii client side validation only for unique key

Tags: php, validation, yii

I want to enable Yii client side (onsubmit & onchange both) validation only for unique key. Currently its working on server side but I want it for both client side and server side.

For rest of form I am using JQuery validation library instead of normal yii model rules validation.

Does anyone has idea how to do this?

Comment: Why -ve? Please explain?

Comment: Can the uniqueness be determined from the form fields (i.e whether `fieldx` differs from `y`)? If not, the only way you can validate your field is server side.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this using scenarios.

Read the documentation on the Yii site regarding the concept : http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/266/understanding-scenarios/

To implement, your controller must create a model with a specified scenario.

```
$model = new Client('register');
```

The model validations will validate according to the rules for the scenario

```
array('name', 'unique', 'className'=>'Client', 'attributeName'=>'name', 'on' => 'register')),
```